# How can I override mat-components in material2 library for angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to design my own UI library, but it should be based on the existing Material 2 library. So just to give you an example, instead of  I should be able to use  which will be just overriding the css of underlying mat-checkbox. I just want to change css, it might be properties like height, width, shadow, padding etc but then I want to allow user to use Input, Output, Two-way binding as it is without writing the boiler plate code, What is the best way to achieve this. Any sort of examples will be helpful.

Comment: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: [Other documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)

Comment: @Maryannah
I do understand that we can override styles of the components, but what if I want something that is equivalent of myCheckboxComponent extends MatCheckBox.

I'm not able to figure out how to just override css and make it as my own component, I want to make a ui library, that can be directly consumed as <my-custom-checkbox> and all updated styles will be used.  I couln't find how to do that using the links that you have mentioned.

Comment: you extend the original class, use the same template, but a different style sheet. Although I wouldn't recommend building your UI library on top of another one ...

Comment: @Maryannah the question is valid, not a duplicate, and should be reopened. It is a question about building custom components on top of angular material components, not about overriding style.